# Problem when introducing figures

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm having trouble when I try to include a figure in my text. The problem is that the text appears behind the image, or the image overlays the text. Also, it's not centred properly.
My code is:

```
\documentclass {article} 
\usepackage {graphicx} 
\begin{document} 
Sample text, sample text, sample text.

\begin{figure}[h!] 
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{circuito.png} 
\caption{Circuito empleado.} 
\end{figure} 

Sample text, sample text, sample text. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems a problem due to wrong dimension information in the PNG file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. How can I fix that? And, by the way, I've tried with JPG files but it keeps happening.

Comment: Try opening the file in, say, paint, then modify the white space in the canvas to fit it properly (you can do this just with the mouse).  Once you have done this, you can set up the `scale` of the figure by using `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{circuito.png}`, where `scale=0.5` is just my guess of the size the picture should be.  Modify as required

Comment: Also, avoid using `begin{center}...\end{center}` inside a `figure` environment.  Use `\centering` at the beginning instead

Comment: I just tried that but I get the same result. The scale of the figure is correct but it keeps appearing misplaced. I also used    `\centering` but nothing happens. I've tried with other images (less "lineal") but I get the same problem, over and over.

I do really appreciate all of your help, thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please write a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?  There must be something else then.

Comment: Sure, I'll try. I made a new document, this is the whole code:
`\documentclass {article}

\usepackage {graphicx}

\begin{document}
Sample text, sample text, sample text.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{circuito.png}
\caption{Circuito empleado.}
\end{figure}

Sample text, sample text, sample text.

\end{document}`

I get the same result. This is how it looks like: [here](http://s23.postimg.org/rdnrbypjv/error2.jpg). I also noticed that there's an error which I don't understand: "Cannot determine size of graphic in circuito.png (no BoundingBox)". Does that help?

Comment: Only pdflatex can reliably handle graphics in png format without additional help. In that case you should view with a PDF reader rather than YAP. YAP can handle png graphics, but plain latex cannot. Latex expects an explicit bounding box in the `\includegraphics` command, or if properly configured, a secondary file containing the bbox information. Back when I used to use MiKTeX, it came with a program (bbox.exe?) that would examine various bitmap graphics formats and write out the appropriate file. Back then you still needed a `\DeclareGraphicsRule` to set the extension of the bbox file.

Comment: Good question, are you using `pdflatex` and a `.pdf` viewer?

Comment: Great, now it works. I believe the problem was that I wasn't using `pdflatex` from the very beggining (I apologize, I'm still a newbie). Now I added `\usepackage [pdftex]{color,graphicx}` and looks fine on the PDF viewer. Still looks weird in YAP, though. I'd look for more information about bounding boxes

Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @PabloOrús, Please, edit your question to add the `circuito.png` alone (BTW, the MWE that you have as a comment look better in this place).